# Run task after packageApplication when using the android gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle has the ability to run tasks after other tasks. The syntax is [taskY.mustRunAfter taskX](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html). The android gradle plugin says one of the ApplicationVariant tasks it defines is [packageApplication](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).

In my build.gradle I have 
`taskX.mustRunAfter packageApplication`

The error I get is "Could not find property 'packageApplication' on project ':someproject'."

Is it even possible to get access to the packageApplication task? If so is it considered bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note this sentence from the documentation:

> By using 'must run after" ordering rule you can specify that taskB
>   must always run after taskA, **whenever both taskA and taskB are
>   scheduled for execution**.

This means that

```
taskX.mustRunAfter packageApplication
```

doesn't make the `taskX` run always after `packageApplication` but just if you type:

```
./gradlew taskX packageApplication
```

On the other hand, it doesn't define a dependency, that is it doesn't automatically run `taskX` task.

To do something, after a task is executed you can use the `doLast` closure:

```
taskX.doLast{ println 'Hello' }
```

The `packageApplication` is a property of the `ApplicationVariant` class but not a task. The tasks are `package<VariantName>`.

Comment: how would you access that property to set it to something else. Also where can you view what these actually do.

Answer (score 8):

I found my the answer. rciovati cleared up the confusion around mustRunAfter and that what I was doing was the wrong approach. 
I ended up converted taskY to a groovy function. Then used the following code:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // rename apk after we assemble the application
    variant.assemble.doLast {
        taskY(variant)
}
```

Comment: I get an error: `the following model rules could not be applied due to unbound inputs and/or subjects:
  android.applicationVariants.all { ... }`